# React update to state/context works sporadically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, react-context

I'm trying to build a React context object that keeps track of the window size so I can use specific components based on window.innerWidth without having to determine the value in multiple places. Ive set the following "DeviceContext" component up:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react"
import { size } from "../utilities/breakpoints"

export const DeviceContext = createContext()

const getSize = () => {
  let width = window.innerWidth > 0 ? window.innerWidth : window.screen.width
  if (width > size.huge) {
    return "huge"
  } else if (width >= size.large) {
    return "large"
  } else if (width >= size.med) {
    return "med"
  } else {
    return "small"
  }
}

export function DeviceProvider({ children }) {
  let [size, setSize] = useState(getSize())

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function resize() {
      setSize(getSize())
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", resize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resize)
    }
  })

  return (
    <DeviceContext.Provider value={size}>{children}</DeviceContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I then wrap my Layout component in `<DeviceProvider>` and consume it in a menu component like this:

```
export const Menu = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <DeviceContext.Consumer>
      {screenSize => {
        if (screenSize === "huge" || screenSize === "large") {
          return <div>Not done yet...</div>
        } else {
          return <ResponsiveNav />
        }
      }}
    </DeviceContext.Consumer>
  )
}

Menu.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.node,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
  ]),
}

export default Menu
```

What I expect to see is "Not done yet..." when window.innerwidth is larger than a specific value and the `<ResponsivNav/>` component when it is not. I expect my context to update when the window is resized (i.e. through dev tools) but it only does so sporadically. If I remove the references to "previous" in my resize method, it doesn't update at all.

Thanks in advance for any advice you might have!

Comment: what's with this line? `setSize(previous => (previous = getSize()))` why not just `setSize(getSize())`. also where is `window.width` defined? do you mean `window.innerWidth` ?

Comment: doh! I had tried several different iterations...changing window.width to window.innerWidth (I had this at one point previous to my copy/past into S/O) and removing the previous=getSize() does help, but every once in a while I still see "Not done yet" on the mobile sized window

Comment: I've edited the original code to refelct the above changes...

Comment: I think it's because you're missing the deps array in your layout effect. what happens when you add an empty array at the end? `useLayoutEffect(() => {..}, [])` ?

Comment: That seems to be much better...adding that I was able to toggle back and forther about 50 times without seeing the wrong version of the menu. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not providing a dependency array in your `useLayoutEffect` the event listener is being readded on every state update. Setting an empty array there will only apply the listener on mount.

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function resize() {
      setSize(getSize())
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", resize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resize)
    }
  }, []) // <--- empty dependency array
```